# AWS RDS Aurora mysql Query Cache

Tags: mysql-5.7, query-cache

AWS RDS mysql 5.7

Current Query Cache is by default enabled on Aurora mysql. (16GB query cache size, on 300GB of RAM). Am facing some deadlocks from Hangfire and it doesn't show anything to having Query Cache locks.

There are 2 blog posts that seem contradictory on the Query Cache feature.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/planning-and-optimizing-amazon-aurora-with-mysql-compatibility-for-consolidated-workloads/

One says enable Query Cache, the other says disable Query Cache. What is the official AWS stance on Query Cache? Is it better to just disable Query Cache in general RDS or not?

Comment: If you have a case where the QC is benefiting your app, start a new Question explain how it is being helpful.  There may be a workaround.

Comment: It was the other way around, we were concerned that QC was affecting our app, but AWS was telling us to leave it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those blog is about MySQL community edition and other is about Aurora MySQL. If configuring MySQL community edition, query cache should be disabled. On MySQL Aurora, it should be enabled.

> Unlike MySQL community edition, where the query cache is being deprecated and disabled as of version 5.7.20, Aurora has a reworked query cache. This query cache doesn’t suffer from the limitations of the implementation in the community edition.

[source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/planning-and-optimizing-amazon-aurora-with-mysql-compatibility-for-consolidated-workloads/)

Comment: cheers thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing this information is quite buried in AWS docs, but I think its worth noting that despite the fact they recommend leaving this setting on and point out that Aurora - AWS removed this functionality from Aurora MySQL 3:

> The query cache is removed from community MySQL 8.0 and also from Aurora MySQL version 3.

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Compare-v2-v3.html)

So if you have any intent to upgrade to version 3, you face a major performance cliff if you do not optimise your application to avoid relying on this cache. Since this version is equivalent to MySQL 8 Community Edition, which offers a great many new features over 5.7, I am surprised AWS doesn't make this clearer.

Comment: thanks RubberDucky!